# Help creating a model to fit raw data to ground truth

Tags: multiple-regression, modeling

[Disclaimer: I searched and could not find "what kinds of questions are allowed on Cross Validated", so let me know up front if this is not the place for this question, and even better: where I should ask.  That would be more helpful than simple down-votes!]

### Context

I'm working with a resistive touch screen on a display.  I need to fit its raw outputs [x_raw, y_raw, z1_raw, z2_raw] to actual [x, y] screen coordinates.

### The challenge

The problem is that the raw data has a strong pressure-sensitive component: when you press harder, the raw values shift.  But the amount of shift depends where on the screen you're pressing.

I've stared at the data sets every which way and tried a bunch of Jupyter / Python models to fit the data and have not gotten any satisfactory results.

### The request

So I'm here to ask: do you want to try your hand at modeling this one?

Here's a link to a spreadsheet with actual x, y pixel coordinates and the raw data when touching those points:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKnvOrhtRvyS3TdDOtnVzl9fJtXgmhMkDdPX8Yi1crw/edit?usp=sharing
```

To give you a sense of what you're up against, here are the data plotted above one another.  (Note: x axis is time, but that shouldn't be relevant in this example.)  You can see that [x_raw, y_raw] *sort of* correlates to [x, y], but with lots of artifacts.  But hopefully the artifacts can be explained with the available data.  And yes, I can provide oodles more data if required...

[image: true x, y pixel coordinates]
[image: raw touch screen data]

### Addendum 1

In the spirit of Cross Validated, even more useful than the model itself would be an explanation of what insights you used to create the model.

### Addendum 2

If the data is just too erratic at the boundaries, an equally useful output of the model would be "the data is valid" bit that says whether or not we can trust the results.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @whuber Thanks for that.  I read over dont-ask, and it appears that my specific question meets the spirit (if not the letter) of the law.  (Aside: is there a link to the dont-ask page from the [ask a question] page?  I couldn't find it...)

Comment: The link is found through our [help], available from the question mark icon at the top right of the Web page.  This question looks too unfocused and general to be suitable here, but perhaps some of the suggestions in the help will enable you to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I may have answered my own question using Support Vector Regression.  The solutions seems to have worked well, but I'd welcome comments for improvement.  (See my notes after the code block):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

dataset = pd.read_csv("touch.csv", header=0)

dataset.head()
```

|  | x | y | x_raw | y_raw | z1_raw | z2_raw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 50.0 | 50.0 | 776 | 13364 | 3468 | 29436 |
| 1 | 50.0 | 50.0 | 7156 | 13780 | 3480 | 29264 |
| 2 | 50.0 | 50.0 | 6924 | 12444 | 3636 | 29152 |
| 3 | 50.0 | 50.0 | 6668 | 13288 | 3548 | 29180 |
| 4 | 50.0 | 50.0 | 6200 | 13048 | 3528 | 28872 |

```
y = dataset.iloc[:,0:1].values.astype(float).ravel()
X = dataset.iloc[:,2:].values.astype(float)
regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)
y_ = regressor.predict(X)
plt.plot(np.arange(0, len(y)), y, y_)
plt.show()
```

[image: SVR output]

A few notes:

- There are large inaccuracies at the transitions, but in the target application, I can handle those by suppressing output until the output stabilizes.
- I'm aware that I'm committing a statistical *faux pas* by using the training data as test data, but my other datasets check out equally well.
- Since all the feature data is more or less in the same range (500 ... 32768) I didn't bother to normalize them.